# How to create a bootstrap job in Play framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a new Play!2.0 project and I am trying to use a startup job.
Here is some code I wrote off of examples I found.

```
package jobs;

import util.*;
import play.jobs.*;

@OnApplicationStart
public class StartupJob extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
        MongoUtil.init();
    }
}
```

When it tried to compile it returns an error:

> package play.jobs does not exist

Looking around the documentation it seems like the play.jobs package existed in 1.0.1 but does not exist in 2.0. Does anybody know what the 2.0 way of doing it is?

Answer (score 5):

In play 2.0 you should use [Global](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaGlobal) object for bootstrap tasks. Jobs have been replaced with [Akka](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaAkka), you can use it to run async tasks.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer!

in play 2.0 you do it with GlobalSetting

look here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal

Comment: Be aware though that when onStart is called will differ between PROD and DEV modes of execution for Play. In Dev mode it will not be called until the first page is requested. In PROD it will be called when the app is started.